# Proof check: Combination of convergent sequences in topological spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, proof-verification

Let $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$   and $\{y_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be two convergent sequences in the topological space $\mathbb{R}$ , such that

$$\lim\{x_n\}=x_0$$ and $$\lim\{y_n\}=y_0$$

Show that:

a) For each $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, the sequence $\{$$ax_n+by_n\}$  is convergent and it converges to $ax_0+by_0$

b) The sequence $\{x_ny_n\}$ converges to $\{x_0y_0\}$

My approach:

By definition
$\forall U \in \tau:  x \in U \implies \left({\exists n_x \in N: \forall n \in N: n > n_x  \implies x_n \in U}\right)$

$\forall V \in \tau: y \in V \implies \left({\exists n_y \in N: \forall n \in N: n > n_y \implies y_n \in V}\right)$

But then:

The sequence $\{ax_n\}$ converges to $ax_0$, since, if a$\neq$0, every open neighborhood of $ax_0$ can be written as $U'=\{ ax : x \in U\}$, and  $n > n_x\implies x_n \in U'$.

If $a=0$, $U'=\{0\}$, and all of the terms of the sequence $\{ax_n\}$ are equal to zero, so  the sequence converges in this set. Since  $U'=\{0\}$ is the smallest set containing $0$, the sequence converges to every neighborhood of $0$.

Similarly, the sequence $\{by_n\}$ converges to $\{by_0\}$.

Now, every open neighborhood of $ax_0+by_0$ (a,b$\neq$0) can be written as $W=\{x+y : x \in U' \text{ and }y \in V'\}$ and if we define $n_0=\max\{n_x, n_y\}$, then $n > n_0 \implies x_n \in W$.

For $a,b=0$ (or at least one of them is equal to zero), a similar argument as the one above about the smallest neighborhood holds so indeed $n > n_0 \implies x_n \in W$, for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

Can someone check if this completes the proof of part a), and is there another way to do it?

Comment: ... Every open neighborhood of $ax_0$ can be written as $U'=\{ax:x\in U\}$... this statement is false. For instance if $\mathbb{R}$ is endowed with its usual topology (Euclidean) and say $x_n\to 1$, if $a=0$ you are saying every open neighbourhood of $0$ can be written as $U'=\{0\}$

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do it?!

Comment: I believe this  depends on the topology you define on $\mathbb R$. I don't think you can prove such a genral statement, without knowing it.

Comment: Actually, now I am skeptic about user160738  comment above. Initially, I thought that the new sequence didn't converge to U'=$\{0\}$, but since now all of the terms of the sequence $\{ax_n\}$ are equal to zero (since a=0), the sequence converges in this set... Maybe I just should modify the sentence "Every open neighborhood...."

Comment: "Now, every open neighborhood of $ax_0+by_0(a,b\neq 0$) can be written as $W=\{x+y:x∈U′ ,y∈V′\}$"- can you explain this agrument in more detail. And by the way, do you know the concept "topological vector space"

Comment: Since $U'$ and $V'$ can be any open set of $ax_0$ and $by_0$, respectively (because, in turn, U and V are, by definition, any open set of $x_0$ and $y_0$, and U',V', are "generated" from them, by definition) so any open set of $ax_0+by_0(a,b\neq 0) $ can be written as W. I am a physicists and I am not used to rigorous math, but I now that you must be able to give an counterexample to show that this is wrong, and I cannot think of one, can you think of an open set that could not be written in such a W?! I don't know about the  " topological vector space" , but I will look for it...